# Custom element's Binding Context - what is it exactly, how to access parent VM

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I couldn't find the answer in the docs, so I'm asking here. What exactly is the binding context passed to the `bind` method of custom element. Is it simply equal to *router's currently active ViewModel*? At least, that's what I've found out so far.

Why isn't it the element's parent (in the terms of DOM) VM?

with this code

```
@customElement("myelem")
@inlineView("<template><content></content></template>")
export class MyElem{
    bind(ctx){
      console.log(ctx);
    }
}

// welcome.html
<myelem>
    <h3>inside myelem</h3>
    <myelem>
      <h4>inside inside ... </h4>
    </myelem>
  </myelem>
```

the output in the console is just current viewmodel (`Welcome`) printed twice.

I'd expect it to be `Welcome` for the first (outer) `myelem`, but `MyElem` for the second (inner) occurance...

Please explain why am I wrong here, and how can the inner custom element be aware of it's actual context (by which I mean the outer one in the case above), without using ugly hacks like creating *secret* property in the "shared" context (the one which actually gets passed to both of them)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In terms of data-binding, both elements are bound to the same binding context.  Consider this example:

```html
<div foo.bind="bar">
  <div foo.bind="bar"></div>
</div>
```

You would expect both `<div>` elements to have the same binding context right?  Both element's `foo` property should be bound to the same model's `bar` property.  The same holds true in this scenario:

```html
<myelem foo.bind="bar">
  <myelem foo.bind="bar"></myelem>
</myelem>
```

Both instances of `<myelem>` are bound to the same binding context / model.

If I understand the question correctly, you would like an elegant way to give the inner MyElem class instance a reference to the outer MyElem class instance.  Luckily, you're using Aurelia so there is a very nice way to do this... declare it as a dependency using the `inject` decorator:

```js
import {inject, Parent} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement("myelem")
@inject(Parent.of(MyElem))
export class MyElem {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  ...
}
```

There's one caveat however...

The Aurelia dependency-injection container's default behavior is to create an instance of the requested item if an instance is not found in the container.  This means that `@inject(Parent.of(MyElem))` is not quite what we want.  In situations where there is no parent MyElem instance the container will create one for us instead of returning null.  Normally we'd use `@inject(Optional.of(MyElem))` to tell the container to give us the instance, only when it exists in the container.  I don't know of a way to combine Parent.of and Optional.of.  I'll create an issue in the aurelia dependency-injection repository so we can get this feature added.

In the meantime, we can easily create our own Resolver that combines the behavior of Parent.of and Optional.of:

```js
import {resolver} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@resolver()
export class OptionalParent {
  constructor(key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  get(container) {
    if (container.parent && container.parent.hasResolver(this.key, false)) {
      return container.parent.get(this.key)
    }
    return null;
  }

  static of(key) {
    return new OptionalParent(key);
  }
}
```

So the new version of our MyElem class would look like this:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {OptionalParent} from './optional-parent';

@customElement("myelem")
@inject(OptionalParent.of(MyElem))
export class MyElem {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  ...
}
```

Here's a working example.  Check the console for log messages showing the result:

https://gist.run/?id=1a84e0a466fb928aa075

Comment: Great, thank you! My first through was "I should've read the DI docs more carefully" but now I see Parent.of isn't documented at all ;)

Comment: Running into this myself. I'll add my use case to the issue later.

Comment: This does not work with the latest Aurelia Plunker (0.8.2), error pertains to `OptionalParent` and says `super() needs to be either null or a function, not undefined`.

Comment: I've updated the code to work with the dependency-injection lib changes in the Nov 2015 Aurelia release