# Custom Element Singletons in Aurelia

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I thought when using dependency injection in Aurelia, you would get singletons by default. That doesn't seem to be the case with custom elements.

Say I have 3 custom elements named `a`, `b` and `c`. `a` and `b` are siblings are the same page. `c` is an element inside of `b`'s template. I'm injecting `c` into `a`.

When I do this, I get a new instance of `c` in `a`. Is there a way to make `c` a singleton?

Here is a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Au80u0?p=preview

Comment: I think I found my answer here: https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/65#issuecomment-161443121

Comment: Some related info, although not quite the same scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32781324/725866

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom elements cannot be singletons because they can be used multiple times, it would not really make sense architecturally that an element could or would act as a singleton.

Imagine referencing the same element 3 times on a page, they would all have the same state if they were singletons and not expected custom element behaviour. However, you can create a shared service class which you inject (and is a singleton).

What I did in an Aurelia project of mine is create a class called MyCustomElementMediator (replace MyCustomElement with the name of your element). This allows you to handle state for a component. This does not make sense for multiple occurrences of a custom element, but if you are only using it in one place, then this approach works.